# How to add Sorted List within another Sorted List in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, sortedlist

I am getting this error because I have a duplicate key in the SortedList.

> Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'V22.1'  Key being added: 'V22.1'

BUT the value of these duplicate keys are different. So I am thinking of adding another object before the preceding the duplicate key in order to find its value. I was thinking of putting SortedList within a SortedList. An illustration for my intention for example:

```
(key)"ICD9" : (key)"V22.1" : (value)"Supervision of other normal pregnancy"
(key)"ICD10" : (key)"V22.1" : (value)"Motorcycle passenger injured in collision with two- or three-wheeled motor vehicle in nontraffic accident"
```

I hope that makes sense. I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
    SortedList<string, SortedList<string, string>> slCodes;
    slCodes = new SortedList<string, SortedList<string, string>>();
```

But the part I am stuck now is how do I add into the SortedList within the SortedList? I am stuck here:

```
    strDesc = tbDesc.Text.Trim();
    tblCodes = new DataTable();
    GetCodesByDescription(strDesc, ref tblCodes); //<--This queries from database
    DataView dvCodes = new DataView(tblCodes);

    dvCodes.RowFilter = "CodeType='ICD10' OR CodeType='ICD9'";
    foreach(DataRowView drv in dvCodes)
    {
        slCodes.Add(drv["Code"].ToString().Trim(), //<--Throws error here.
            drv["Description"].ToString().Trim());
    }
```

This is currently where I am stuck at on adding into the SortedList within a SortedList. I'm not even sure if this approach to having a key-value pair within a key is correct. Please help.

Comment: Can you give us more explanation of the data that you want to see as a result of this process? Set aside the specific collection type (`SortedList`) and please describe sample input and output.

Comment: You need to be checking to see if drv["Code"].ToString() is already in slCodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first check the code type to determine which sub list to add to and if you need to create a new sub list.

```
foreach(DataRowView drv in dvCodes)
{
    var codeType = drv["CodeType"].ToString().Trim();
    var code = drv["Code"].ToString().Trim();
    var description = drv["Description"].ToString().Trim();
    if(slCodes.ContainsKey(codeType))
    {
        slCodes[codeType].Add(code, description);
    }
    else
    {
        var subList = new SortedList<string, string>();
        subList.Add(code, description);
        slCodes.Add(codeType, subList);
    }
}
```

Alternatively since you only pull ICD9 and ICD10 codes you could prepopulate the two sub lists

```
var slCodes = new SortedList<string, SortedList<string, string>>();
slCodes.Add("ICD9", new SortedList<string, string>());
slCodes.Add("ICD10", new SortedList<string, string>());

dvCodes.RowFilter = "CodeType='ICD10' OR CodeType='ICD9'";
foreach(DataRowView drv in dvCodes)
{
    var codeType = drv["CodeType"].ToString().Trim();
    var code = drv["Code"].ToString().Trim();
    var description = drv["Description"].ToString().Trim();
    slCodes[codeType].Add(code, description);
}
```

Comment: Wow this is awesome. This makes a lot of sense to me. Now I can start figuring out how to loop through each sorted list within sorted list. Which isn't much of a problem now since the design of the sorted list is not so difficult. This is awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

slCodes is a SortedList object containing strings for keys and `SortedList <string, string>` for values, but you are not adding these types to it; rather 2 string objects.

You need to add a string and a `SortedList <string, string>`, instead of 2 string objects.

If you want to add something to an existing sorted list in slCodes, then you must first look up said list before adding 2 strings to it.